# Optimize the expected payoff using a normal distribution

Tags: c++, optimization, normal-distribution

Suppose I generate a normal distribution with mean 50, and standard deviation 1.

```
boost::normal_distribution<> normal(50, 1);
```

I would then like to multiply this normal distribution by the payoff function given by:

*f(x) = 100 - x*

and then solve for the maximum x \in [0, 100].

In particular, I wish to solve:

((max x /in [0,100]) normal(x) * (100 - x)

Can someone please help me code this, or lead me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you explain the problem a bit more? Are you looking for the maximum of `x(100-x)` where `x` has a normal distribution? Do you want to select a few `x`s from a normal distribution and find the maximum of `x(100-x)` for those values of `x` or do you want to know the theoretical maximum?

Comment: @triple_r Note that the normal distribution, normal(x), and ,f(x) = 100 - x, both have the same independent variable. I simple wish to multiply the two functions for every x, and then maximize over all x \in [0, 100]. Is that clear?

Comment: Oh, so by `normal(x)` do you mean the probability density function for a normal distribution at `x`? something like [this](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/gif/norpdf.gif)?

Comment: @triple_r Yes. x is the independent variable that varies along the x-axis.

Comment: @triple_r And by multiplying normal(x) by the payoff function (for every x), I would generate the expected payoff function.

Comment: I see, so you probably need `pdf(normal, x) * (100 - x)`, right? and you want to find the maximum of that using code and not mathematically. Sorry for asking a lot of questions, just want to be clear before answering :-)

Answer (score 1):

The PDF (probability distribution function) for a normal distribution has a nice closed form:

[image: pdf(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}]

so it is possible to find the maximum analytically by solving for:

[image: \frac{d}{dx}\left(pdf(x)(100-x)\right)=0]

which is going to result in `x=75-sqrt(626)` or `x=49.98` for your case.

However, if you want to do it in a code and not analytically, you can use an optimization algorithm. In your case, probably a simple algorithm such as golden section search (in one dimension) will work just fine ([here, for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_section_search)):

```
using boost::math::normal;

normal ndist(50.0, 1.0);

double f(const double &x)
{
    return pdf(ndist, x) * (100.0 - x);
}

double max(double (*f)(const double &), double &a, double &b, const double tol = 1e-5)
{
    static double goldenratio = 0.618034;
    double c = b - goldenratio * (b - a);
    double d = a + goldenratio * (b - a);
    while(abs(c - d) > tol)
    {
        double fc = (*f)(c); double fd = (*f)(d);
        if (fc > fd)
        {
            b = d;
            d = c;
            c = b - goldenratio * (b - a);
        } else
        {
            a = c;
            c = d;
            d = a + goldenratio * (b - a);
        }
    }
    return 0.5 * (b + a);
}
```

a good starting bracket is `0` and `100`:

```
double a = 0.0;
double b = 100.0;
maximum = max(f, a, b);
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining how to solve that derivative in c++?

Comment: with the golden section search you don't need to calculate the derivative. Some optimization algorithms need the derivative, and for those algorithms, you can either calculate the derivative analytically (symbolically) and put in your code, or use a numerical differentiation method. For example, with a central difference scheme `dfdx = (f(x+eps) - f(x-eps)) / (2.0*eps)` (`eps` is a small number, let's say `eps=1e-10`).

Comment: I'm confused by the optimization algorithm. Also, why don't you specify what fc and what fd are? They are never declared it seems.

Comment: The `max` function here is an optimization algorithm. It tries to find the maximum of a function `f` in a given interval `[a,b]`. This is just one such algorithm, there are many. Some use derivative of the function, some don't. The one I've listed doesn't need to know about the derivative.

Comment: `fc` and `fd` are the values of function `f` at `c` and `d` and they have been defined right after the `while` statement. I copied the code from the wikipedia pseudo-code so there are some mistakes in it, I'll edit my answer to fix those :-)

Comment: My compiler is giving me an error when I assign b to d. This is because b is passed by constant reference.

Comment: Thanks, How would I call this function in main(), i.e. max(f(), 0, 100, tol); That doesn't work.

Comment: Added a sample call to the example. Also, there was a typo in golden ratio (it should be `0.618...`), make sure to change that in your code.

Comment: I am getting run time errors when calling max(): Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error C2780 '_Ty std::max(std::initializer_list<_Elem>,_Pr)': expects 2 arguments - 3 provided, Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error C2782 'const _Ty &std::max(const _Ty &,const _Ty &,_Pr)': template parameter '_Ty' is ambiguous

Comment: It is complaining about the name `max` because it is confusing it with `std::max` (don't know why). Change the name to something else and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: I don't have boost on my work machine to test your code, but removing all the boost-related stuff, there is only one error and that is because of redefining the default parameter. So, on line 53 of your code, remove `= 1e-5` because you have already told compiler what the default value is going to be in line 32. Also, to get the output of the function do something like `std::cout << maxx(f, a, b) << std::endl;`. Can you post the errors that you are getting after fixing that default parameter?